# How do you annotate a matplotlib imshow map with an arrow *and* text?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to make an illustration that looks like this:

[image: better image]

But instead I get this:

[image: basic image]

Here is my program:

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import colors
# A = [[1,2,3,4,5]]
A = [[0],[1]]
Amap = colors.ListedColormap(['blue','green'])

figure(1)
imshow(A, cmap=Amap, interpolation='nearest')
annotate('AA BB',xy=(0,0), xytext=(.8,0), fontsize=20)
axis('off')
savefig('graph-py.pdf')
show()
```

I've tried everything to get the arrow, but can't seem to make it happen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually look through the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) to find examples of what I want to do. [annotation_demo2](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo2.html) looked similar to what you wanted  ...  I came up with this.  Looks like you were missing the [arrowprops kwarg](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate).

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import colors
# A = [[1,2,3,4,5]]
A = [[0],[1]]
Amap = colors.ListedColormap(['blue','green'])

fig = figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False)
imshow(A, cmap=Amap, interpolation='nearest')
ax.annotate('AA BB', fontsize=20, xy=(.25, .75),
            xycoords='data', xytext=(150, -6),
            textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            linewidth = 5.,
                            color = 'red')
            )
ax.annotate('CC DD', fontsize=20, xy=(.25, .25),
            xycoords='data', xytext=(150, -6),
            textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(width = 5.,
                            headwidth = 15.,
                            frac = 0.2,
                            shrink = 0.05,
                            linewidth = 2,
                            color = 'red')
            )
axis('off')
savefig('graph-py.pdf')
show()
close()
```

Looks like this:

[image: annotate example]

Comment: Thanks! I did look through the gallery and couldn't get it to work. Glad you found my bug!

Comment: I think I like the YAArow patch better than the FancyArrowPatch